# Instagram API & IOS

Tags: ios, instagram-api

I have no idea why instagram team never thought to be more friendly with mobile apps integration
All what am trying to do is to read the JSON of the posts for a specific HashTag in my mobile app, and all what i found is a very basic tutorial how to get access token for the user, and million guides to [this page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_search) !!

and when i try to check the result directly on the browser
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/challenge/media/recent?access_token=TOKEN

All i got is this:

> {"pagination":{"deprecation_warning":"next_max_id and min_id are
>   deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id
>   instead"},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}

Does any one has any idea what steps exactly should i follow to get the needed info? cuz spending too much time on this part upsets me!!

For instance, i followed exactly [this tutorial](http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/instagram-api-integration-in-ios-application/2/) to get the authorization and access token in my app

Comment: I know nothing about Instagram but read the error in the JSON you posted. Use the property parameter names in your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in Sandbox mode, so it will return only media from your sandbox authorized user, here is information about this:

> As another example, let's consider an endpoint that returns a list of
>   media: /tags/{tag-name}/media/recent. The response returned by this
>   endpoint will contain only media with the given tag, as expected. But
>   instead of returning media from any public Instagram user, it will
>   return only media that belongs to your sandbox users, restricted to
>   the last 20 for each user.

Here is the link to more details about Sandbox mode: https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Once your app is approved, you will see all media.

Try searching for a hashtag that you have posted with your account, that will showup in result